# Did they remove the images in asset folder from appearing in the intellisense menu in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, intellisense

I remember back in Xcode 8 or 9, when you started typing out code, Xcode displayed the images inside the asset folder to the Intellisense menu. So when I was typing, say I had an image called "House", if I typed in the word "house", the image would appear in the list and when I selected it the image would appear in the line of code.

What's appearing now:

[image: Whats appearing now]

As you can see now from the photo the image is not there in code anymore and there is a stock basic image icon taking it place.

Did they knowingly choose to remove images from Intellisense or is there some sort of flag I need to set now to allow the images to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we have `Image Literal`, just type it, select it and choose the image you want.

**Usage**:

`<#ImageView#>.image = Image Literal`

**Notes**:

- Sometimes it doesn't work properly with less than 2 images on the project.
- Build the project if you're not seeing recently added images.

More knowledge about it here: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/be-literal-76e9b4389eda